# ERROR EN INSERT MULTIPLE

Tags: php, json, array

Buen dia a todos,

Tengo un problema al insertar datos

El array en total son 96 registros los cuales cuando acaba el array y mando todos los datos y valores correcto al archivo "guardar.php" no me lee nada de los valores fijos (CAMPOS TEXT) pero si me manda los 96 datos dentrod e la tabla, con registros de 10 o 20 o 30 rows si los inserta correcto pero este caso que son 96 marca error por valores vacios

```
No pude hacer la consulta INSERT INTO conceptos (folio,sucursal,acreedor,importe,fechaprog,fechapago,cuentabanco,ref_pago,tipo,referencia, id_concepto, solicito_gasto) VALUES (154799,,'',,'','','','','','', 0, '')
```

"ACLARANDO LOS DATOS LOS MANDO MEDIANTE UN JSON"

Espero su ayuda de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Debes leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y [edit] la pregunta: Si tienes valores vacíos, ¿por qué no le envías un valor por defecto?, debes explicar mejor tu problema en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un Operador ternario por cada parámetro que envíes para que condiciones si esta vació agregue un valor por default, ejemplo

```
$Valor = $_POST['parametro']==''?'Vacio':$_POST['parametro'];
```